# Stylistic differences between чтобы and дабы

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

In a recent Russian composition, one of my sentences was changed to the following by a native:

> Ну точнее, сначала она хотела, чтобы я **лишь** заглядывал в её квартиру
>   по вечерам, **дабы** ее собаки не чувствовали себя в полном одиночестве в ее
>   отсутствие.

In her comments, she mentioned that the use of **дабы** in conjunction with **лишь** would prepare the listener/reader for the eventual complication to this plan, and would additionally lend the entire sentence an air of irony. I find this intriguing, but need a little more information and examples as to what she means by this. I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly the change and its explanation sound a little random to me, especially the **лишь**. And whatever "air of irony" there is just gets lost in the overall stylistic heaviness of the last clause, which is a little at odds with the lighter and more colloquial tone introduced by **Ну точнее**.

Here's how I would reword, aiming for stylistic cohesion:

> Ну точнее, сначала она хотела, чтобы я **просто** заглядывал **к ней в** квартиру по вечерам, **а то собакам** в её отсутствие **будет совсем одиноко**.

**Дабы**, as others have mentioned, is archaic — or perhaps just very formal; a rough equivalent of "in order that" followed by subjunctive.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolay! Perhaps if you read the entire passage, her suggested devices would make more sense. I'm all for stylistic creativity in writing, but it has to have cohesion, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

- Using outdated word -- some people might think it funny
- avoiding second "чтобы" in the same sentence

But overall it doesn't make much sense for me in this case. You know, stylistics is a thing to be "served" for one's personal taste. Neither "лишь", nor "дабы" has something humourous by itself.

See also [What are the advanced Russian words якобы and дабы?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12284/what-are-the-advanced-russian-words-%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-and-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Using archaic words for an everyday context does create an ironic effect, but is rarely met in everyday speech nowadays. It is often used in fiction and newspapers though as a literary device. See the examples from the National Corpus with **дабы**(meaning **чтобы**):

> Другие покупают своему ещё не родившемуся "юному гению" зайцевские таблицы для обучения чтению и письму, дабы не потерять потом ни одного драгоценного дня ― а ну как их малыш окажется в числе "отстающих", и к трем (!) годам не сможет прочесть "мама мыла раму". [Мария Давыдова. Кто в доме хозяин? (2003)
>
> В Сибирь приехали учёные люди из Оксфорда, дабы просветить омичей на предмет избавления от мусора. [Омский мусорный абзац (2003)
>
> Автомобиль Панкрашина стоял там, где указал водитель, перед входом в здание клубного типа, где и переговоры удобно проводить, и ресторан есть, дабы заполировать удачную сделку совместной трапезой. [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]
>
> Максим заканчивал привилегированные курсы, дабы его новый костюм из “Хэрродз”, супруга и акцент полностью соответствовали тому рафинированному обществу, в которое он так неожиданно попал. [Нина Щербак. Роман с филфаком // «Звезда», 2010]

**Лишь** means **только** and is used to express "limitation " (only we didn't sleep...see the example. )

> Лишь мы одни бодрствовали в этом мире, непреклонно приближаясь к своей великой цели. [Булат Окуджава. Искусство кройки и житья (1985)]